# Wordpress shows fatal error after moving to a different server

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

After I have moved GoDaddy to a different server VPC Wordpress shows

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/rm/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 110

When I try to log in as admin:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in /home/rm/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 297

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste this code in wp-config.php file.

**define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );**

This code tells WordPress to increase the PHP memory limit to 256MB.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Tnx - Sorry i can see that what code is shows - but your answer is not good as it wont works - i have tried that before raise this question on stackoverflow

Comment: Why not raise the memory limit from your cPanel or talk to the host to find out to raise the limit.

Comment: omukiguy: im using VPS there is no limitation i think - however i will check this - many thanks